# How can STATCOM output voltage higher than system voltage?

Tags: voltage

I’ve read about the multi-pulse vs. multi-level, etc., but I’m hoping an example will be fine with just a 6 pulse H-Bridge STATCOM with triangular carrier PWM.

In order to inject reactive power, the output voltage of the STATCOM must be higher than the system voltage (and in phase with system voltage). How can the STATCOM ever charge it’s DC capacitor to a voltage higher than the present system voltage (the same voltage it uses to charge its capacitor)?

I keep reading that the STATOM can vary its output angle in order to draw active power to charge the capacitor to maintain its DC charge level, but I keep coming to the same question of how can it get its voltage higher than the system while also charging from the same system? Or is it that if the system voltage drops, then since its already charged at the higher voltage level it can then inject reactive power until the active power losses drain its charge to the level of the voltage dip at which point it’s no longer able to inject anymore reactive power. Does it reach some balance level where it is injecting reactive power which keeps the voltage up while at the same time maintaining its charge at that same level?

PSCAD has an example model of a 6 pulse STATCOM which charges its DC bus to levels higher than the present system voltage, which to me seems impossible.

Below is a picture of the 6 pulse STATCOM I'm visualizing:
[image]
6 Pulse VSC

Comment: Look up a multi level converter, MLC, there it's easier to see that bypassing cells will charge the inserted ones to a voltage. Next half-cycle, you can insert charge the previously bypassed cells and bypass the previously inserted and voilà, you have more than the system voltage to play around with.

Comment: So is it not possible with the 6 pulse VSC as shown above? I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "bypassing cells". Would you mind further clarifying?

Comment: Never said that. Google "multi level converter". Also see UweD's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the DC voltage theoretically as high as you want for such a topology because it is a boot-type converter. The basic relationship for the DC-link voltage is

Udc = 2*Unmax/M

with modulation index M in a range [0 .. 1.15], dependent on the modulation signal of your PWM

Unmax ... amplitude of converter input phase voltage (not line-line but line-ground)

Comment: Is it boot or boost?

Comment: Sorry, it's boost.